# perf tool missing arm_spe event

Tags: events, profiling, arm64, perf

I am new to perf tool. I am using AlmaLinux 8.8 on arm64.

I have installed perf:
perf --version
perf version 4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.aarch64

The arm_spe event seems to be missing:

perf list | grep -i arm_spe

How can I enable or fix this event?

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-arm-spe.1.html

Thanks

google search with no resolution

Comment: Are you sure your AArch64 CPU supports SPE?  You didn't mention a CPU model so we can't check for you. `perf list` only lists events that your system supports.   Does `perf record -e arm_spe//` do anything?  It seems like a special thing, perhaps a different mode of operation from other events, which might explain why it's not in `perf list`.  Or maybe your `perf` and kernel versions are just too old;   Linux 4.18 was released in Nov 2018, about 5 years ago.  I wouldn't be surprised if `arm_spe` is newer than that.

Comment: thank you, you have pointed me in the right direction. I need to move to newer kernel first.